# External HHD won't copy large files

Tags: filesystems

I have Buffalo HD_PXU2 (with password protection) and I'm trying to move a very important file of 90 GB (it's a virtual PC Hard disk and should be taken all) but once I try to copy I get the message
"The file is too large for the destination file system". what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reformat the disk with a file system that allows files that big. FAT doesn't allow them, NTFS might allow them.

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is probably is FAT32. 
In FAT32, a single file's size cannot be more than 4GB. 
You need to convert the disk to NTFS as follows:

1. Run command prompt as administrator
2. Run `convert <drive letter>: /fs:ntfs`
3. e.g. `convert f: /fs:ntfs`

Though the process is official and pretty safe, please backup all the important data first.

Ideally, no data is lost during conversion. But, its always wiser to backup important data.